# Deploy helloworld to wildfly using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I want to deploy my helloworld project to my wildfly (former jboss) application server.
I can use maven `mvn install wildfly:deploy` and it will deploy the app.

But when I want to use eclipse to `run on Server` it does nothing.
I don't get a console output or anything which looks like building and deploying.
I added the server runtime to the project and also added the wildfly server.

Why is Eclipse not deploying?

Comment: What version of eclipse/jboss tools are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me: do a `mvn install` in order to build the war and have it at the target folder. Then right-click on wildfly-server. You will see an `add-remove` option. Click on it, select your project from the list and then add your project to the server. Click finish. If the server is running the project should be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to simply copy the war from your target directory and place it in the `standalone/deployments` folder of your wildfly installation.
Make sure that you have stopped the server before copying the war. After you have copied the war to the deployments folder, start he server.
Your application should be deployed successfully.